# Changing audio input using Java?

Tags: java, audio, microphone, javasound

I'd like to modify the audio input stream, the stream that would come
from my microphone.
I have looked through the java.sound package API, but did not entirely understand it,
nor how to modify direct sound input.

Does anyone here know how to do that, or know an API that is capable of doing it?

Comment: *"modify the audio input stream"*  Can you possibly vague that up more for me?  Modify how (specifically)?  Modifying the volume is a lot simpler than either of a) Doing a low-pass filter b) Extracting the sections of bird song.

Answer (score 2):

You want a mixture of things:

- The Java Sound system: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-139508.html
- A trail for it: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/index.html
- Using audio controls: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/sound/programmer_guide/chapter6.html (part of a wider set of documentation)

If you are able to give more information about what you want to do to the audio stream, it's likely we'll be able to give you more specific advice.

Comment: +1.  See also the [JavaSound info. page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/javasound/info) for some good links.