# Need Help for this flow (AudioInputStream -> byte Array -> AudioOutputStream)

Tags: java, audio, arrays, javasound

I'm making a program which modifies original sound.

my program's process is here.

1. Get sound from **AudioInputStream**
2. Change sound data into **byte array**.(My AudioFormat's **frame size** is **4**. So, I'll use byte array with length **4**)
3. Modify byte array(something like *"multiply -1 to every element"*)
4. Send modified byte array to **AudioOutputStream**
5. Sound is played.

I did process 1 and 2 and 3.

Here is my **CODE** for process 1, 2, 3

```
try {
  byte[] packet = new byte[4];
  int result;

  while((result = audioInputStream.read(packet)) != -1)
    for(int i = 0;i < 4;i++)
      reflectedPacket[i] = (byte)(-1 * packet[i]);

      //I think I have to do something to send packet to AudioOutputStream in here
  }
catch(IOException ioe) {
  System.out.println(ioe.getMessage());
}
```

However, I do not know how to do process 4, *Send modified byte array to **AudioOutputStream***

I saw a source which use ByteArrayInputStream.

However, it was source which reads file, not AudioInput :(

How can I do process 4 and 5?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are reading your `audioInputStream` into the `byte` array correctly. Try replace your `while` and nested `for` loops with:

```
int framesize = 4;
byte[] packet = new byte[framesize];
int numBytesRead = audioInputStream.read(packet, 0, framesize);
for(int i = 0; i < numBytesRead; i++)
  reflectedPacket[i] = (byte)(-1 * packet[i]);
```

By the way, I think that is a very **bad** way to modify your audio stream. Please take a look at the [Java Sound Info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javasound/info) page and this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8806010/1144203) for some useful links to modify audio stream.

Anyway.... once you have modified your audio stream, you can use [`AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(java.io.InputStream)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/AudioSystem.html#getAudioInputStream(java.io.InputStream)), to perform your step 4, like this:

```
AudioInputStream newStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(reflectedPacket));
```

Finally, you will need the [`Clip`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/Clip.html) interface to play the sound:

```
Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
clip.open(newStream);
```

Answer (score 0):

The 'AudioOutputStream' you are looking for is called [`SourceDataLine`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/playing.html). It can be acquired from AudioSystem and there is a [tutorial here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/playing.html).

However, as a warning,

> My AudioFormat's frame size is 4.

Unless your audio is 8-bit with 4 channels (I can pretty much guarantee it's not), negating the bytes will just sound like distortion. This is because the bytes in the frame are 'packed', for example:

```
big-endian 16-bit stereo PCM frame

  b[0]     b[1]     b[2]     b[3]
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000

where:
 - b[0] = left channel high byte
 - b[1] = left channel low byte
 - b[2] = right channel high byte
 - b[3] = right channel low byte
```

To unpack this frame, you can do

```
int ch0 = (b[0] << 8) | (b[1] & 0xFF);
int ch1 = (b[2] << 8) | (b[3] & 0xFF);
```

To pack this frame, you can do

```
b[0] = (byte)((ch0 >>> 8) & 0xFF);
b[1] = (byte)( ch0        & 0xFF);
b[2] = (byte)((ch1 >>> 8) & 0xFF);
b[3] = (byte)( ch1        & 0xFF);
```

For little-endian, the high and low bytes are reversed.

See also: [JSR FAQ](http://www.jsresources.org/faq_audio.html#reconstruct_samples).

Comment: Thank you for answer! I'm sorry but, could you give me more detail about **How byte array from AudioInputStream looks like**? I noticed that 4-bytes array from AudioInputStream means left chaneel high byte / left-low / right-high / right-low. I've never seen explanation like this.

Comment: What I want to make is Active Noise Cancellation. So I have to make antiphase of input sound(AudioInputStream). And write it to speaker. Is there any advice for Active Noise Cancellation?

Comment: *"How byte array from AudioInputStream looks like?"* This really requires a lengthy explanation. The Java Sound Resources FAQ contains a lot of answers explaining this type of thing, in particular [*'How are samples organized in a byte array/stream?'*](http://www.jsresources.org/faq_audio.html#samples_organized)

Comment: ANC, the idea is simple but it assumes you have a recording of the outside noise. You flip the noise signal and add it to the playback and voila, noise appears gone. Not really sure what advice you are asking for. In a real system you would need to calibrate the amplitude of the noise because if the user turns up the volume the flipped noise will become audible. It is probably done best as a hardware device. If you are just wanting to learn, you can calibrate it yourself.